# Optimizing MySQL Join and Group By with intermediate table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Simplifying but I have three tables:

- users (user_id, team_id)
- results (user_id, result)
- user_signups (user_id, team_id, event_id)

results.user_id is a foreign key.

Tables have large number of rows in. If I do

```
select sum(result)
from results
inner join users on users.id = results.user_id
group by team_id
```

It is fast. "Explain" has results with 150k rows, users with 1 row.

If I do

```
select sum(result)
from results
inner join user_signups on user_signups.user_id = results.user_id
where event_id = 1
group by team_id
```

It is very slow (from 1 second to 14). "Explain" has results with 28 rows, user_signups with 5345 rows.

Things I have tried:

A unique index on event_id and user_id on user_signups.

An index on event_id, user_id, team_id on user_signups.

Rewriting as

```
select sum(result)
from results
inner join (select * from user_signups where event_id = 1) user_signups on user_signups.user_id = results.user_id
group by team_id
```

Rewriting as

```
select sum(result)
from results
inner join users on users.id = results.user_id
inner join user_signups on user_signups.user_id = users.id
where event_id = 1
group by user_signups.team_id
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: please identify the existing indexes on each table and suggest you show the explain plan results in your question, sample data and expected result would help too (perhaps setup a sqlfiddle? sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Go read some of the other questions on mysql query optimization. Generally they get down voted or poor answers when they don't have details of the schema and explain plans.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 0):

By grouping on the team_id, I assume that you want one row for each record in `results`.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT *, sum(result) FROM results
LEFT JOIN users ON (users.user_id=results.user_id)
LEFT JOIN user_signups ON (user_signups.users_id=users.user_id)
GROUP BY table.field
```

From here, you can group on whatever you like.  This structure assumes that most of your data will be present in the results table and will join users to the results table and user_signups to the users table.

Comment: Do you really believe that will be faster?

Comment: If the user_id fields are properly index, it should.

Comment: No. At **best** a `LEFT JOIN` will take just as long as an `INNER JOIN` but in most cases it will be significantly slower, and will return a *different value*

Comment: That depends on the result set you are trying to obtain.  If your primary concern is the sum of results, then using the Left Join will look for results first, then join the users to that table.  So in fact it would be faster in this case.

Comment: No it won't. Try it if you don't believe me. And that's not the query you've provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Make the multicolumn index on (event_id, user_id, team_id) in user_signups table and try to run the following query.
If this doesn't work then post your explain here.

```
select sum(result) from results inner join(select
event_id,user_id,team_id from user_signups where event_id = 1)
user_signups on user_signups.user_id = results.user_id group by
team_id
```